# Find out widget class in TclTK

Tags: class, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have several buttons in a window and I want to change the pady value for all of then. I can do:

```
foreach a [list b1 b2 b3 ... bn] {
   grid configure $a -pady 2
}
```

But this is slow since I have to look for all the path and if I change the interface then I have to update the list by hand. So I was thinking about doing:

```
foreach a [winfo children $win] {
    if {[winfo class $a] == "TButton"} {
        grid configure $a -pady 2
    }
}
```

But I can not found the class of the widget anywhere. Can I even do this in TclTk? If yes, could anyone point me to a list of class values for `winfo class widget_path`?

Answer (score 0):

`winfo children` only gives you the direct children. If any of your buttons are contained in e.g. frames, they won't be returned in the list.

[The wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1327) has code to create a list of all widgets regardless of depth:

```
proc wlist {{W .}} {
    set list [list $W]
    foreach w [winfo children $W] {
        set list [concat $list [wlist $w]]
    }
    return $list
}
```